# Add html after every 2 divs

Tags: php, jquery, html

I tried to find a solution in js or php but I wasn't able to solve my issue:
I have lots of divs, and I want to add html after every two divs.
This is an example:

```
<div>
    Some content
</div>
<div>
    Some other content
</div>
<!--Here i want to display some html-->
<div>
    Some content
</div>
```

**Is there an easy way to add a string in html after a certain number of divs with the same class?**

Comment: Sure there is. Just iterate over the divs and have a counter. Now when a certain number is reached (or e.g. `%2==0`), you'll add extra content. Possible in both, JS or PHP - but you still have to do it yourself

Comment: I tried using jquery function .append but i was unable to append the html after every two divs, i tried googling a solution but i haven't found anything helpful. Thank you.

Comment: @Benjamin, check out my answer. It addresses your problem.

Comment: Asks to code for him without any attempt himself.

Comment: @MaksimsMihejevs, perhaps you could explain why Benjamin shouldn't do that, instead of just complaining about him from the third person's perspective?

Comment: If @Benjamin has requirement to achieve what he asks in his question, then there is demand for some skill. If there is lack of skill - it has to be achieved. The process of learning involves getting knowledge and then practice to make information stable as mechanism - skill. Asking: "please do something for me" - is not courage to learn. If he is a employee and asked to do things - that is business mistake or employee who did not explained his incapability. If he is student - then it's twice bad, and should fail early - don't waste peoples time if you can't invest your own in own future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this simple code:

```
$("div:nth-child(2n)").after('<div>Test</div>');
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use:

```
$("div:nth-child(2n)")
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2RXLe/)**

Comment: Your solution is very interesting i gave it a +1
Altough the best one is that provided by Adnan.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can make a simple loop :

```
for (var i=0;i<$(".someclass").length;i++)
{
  if (i%2 == 0)
  {
    $($(".someclass")[i]).after("insert something");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this in jQuery you can use this:

```
$("div:nth-child(2n)").after("something after the element");
```

For php you would use something like:

`($i % 2) == 1)` if your loop starts with `0`

`($i % 2) == 0)` if your loop starts with `1`

Comment: Your solution is right. I gave you a +1, but Adnan suggested that before you. Thank you very much! I appreciate the help!

Comment: @Benjamin I just answer questions here because I find much useful informations here too, so I don't care about the reputation point I have :D. You don't have to change the accepted answer, but if you want to accept the answers upon the time they where posted, you should take care because they are not sorted by time and you should look at the time displayed in the tooltip shown when you are over the `answered ... ` (if it is shown as x hours ago)

Comment: @t-niese thank you very much ;) I only wanted you to know that your help was really appreciated! A +1 for the question was the minimum!

Answer (score 1):

You may use jquery's each

```
// get all the divs on page
var divs = $('div');

// Iterate through each of the divs
$(divs).each(function (index, elem){
   // if the current div is the an even one
   if ((index % 2) === 0)) {
      // add html after it
      $(elem).after('your html goes here');
   }
});
```

Although, I'd suggest using @Milind Anantwar, @Adnan's answer ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can add JavaScript to perform this action.

```
$nd = 0;
$("div").each(function() {
   $nd++;

   if($nd%2==0)
   {
       $(this).after("<span>Some Html...</span>");
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A JQuery solution. I am using 3n because it gives what the questioner wants.

http://jsfiddle.net/2RXLe/1/

[image]

```
$("div:nth-child(3n)").each(function () {
    $(this).html('Here i want to display some html')

})
```

Comment: the loop start with `$i=0`,  `0 % 2` is `0` so it adds it after the first element and then after every second element.

Comment: I removed the PHP solution as jQuery is sufficient. Check my Fiddle, it does exactly what the questioner intended. 2n isn't right.

Comment: I saw an intermediate state. But it is still wrong it replaces every third element and does not **insert** after every second element.

Comment: Well, even though the question says, every 2 divs, he actually meant something else, so I have given him the code that responds to his example.